# java.io.FileNotFoundException /employee.xml: open failed ENOENT (No such file or directory) on file read

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, readfile

I receive `java.io.FileNotFoundException /employee.xml: open failed ENOENT (No such file or directory)` when trying to read from an XML file.

Class to create my XML file:

```
public class Filesauv {
public static void lance() {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
        //add elements to Document
        Element rootElement =
            doc.createElementNS("http://www.journaldev.com/application", "Applications");
        //append root element to document
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);


        //for output to file, console
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        //for pretty print
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        //write to console or file
        StreamResult console = new StreamResult(System.out);
        StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File("employee.xml"));

        //write data
        transformer.transform(source, console);
        transformer.transform(source, file);
        System.out.println("DONE");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 
}
```

Class to read from my XML file and add inside it:

```
public class ModifyXMLDOM extends MainActivity {
  public static void lance(){

      String filePath = "employee.xml";
        File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


            //add new element
            addElement(doc);

            //write the updated document to file or console
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("employee.xml"));
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");

        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException | TransformerException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

}

private static void addElement(Document doc) {
    NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("Applications");
    Element emp = null;

    //loop for each employee

        emp = (Element) employees.item(0);
        Element appliElement = doc.createElement("application");
        Element serviceElement1 = doc.createElement("messagerie");
        Element serviceElement2 = doc.createElement("repertoire");
        Element serviceElement3 = doc.createElement("calculatrice");
        Element serviceElement4 = doc.createElement("calendrier");

        serviceElement1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(m));
        serviceElement2.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(re));
        serviceElement3.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ca));
        serviceElement4.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(cale));

        appliElement.appendChild(serviceElement1);
        appliElement.appendChild(serviceElement2);
        appliElement.appendChild(serviceElement3);
        appliElement.appendChild(serviceElement4);

        emp.appendChild(appliElement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I commend you on your attempted English. Mais, je parle le Francais aussi.

Vous devez utiliser

```
File f = new File("employee.xml");
f.createNewFile();
```

avant vous utilisez vos programme. Vous n'avez pas un fichier pour ecriver. Donc, vous devez le creer.

Comment: bonjour merci de votre repense, donc tout cella avant méme de faire appel a  Filesauv.lance(); ,car ca a marché dans un projet java c'est la methode lance de filesauv qui s'occupe de le crée .

Comment: Hmm, essayez un autre dossier dans `StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File("employee.xml"));` comme `StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "employee.xml"));`

Comment: C'est bon merci je l'ai resolut j'ai caremment mis le chemin brute du fichier bref, maintenent je dois envoyer mon fichie depuis l'applicatio. Android vers une application serveur avec des sockets tout ca sur mon ordinateur cad l'emulateur et l'appli java ,je sais pas si vous pouvez m'orienté? , merci pour votre repence .